# Is it possible to show/hide SSRS PageNumber programmatically?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, reporting-services

Is it programmatically possible to hide the page number label which is shown in SSRS Report ? Currently it is shown in the PageFooter of the report.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page number is a global value displayed inside a textbox.

If you wish to remove it altogether, then you may delete the textbox.

If you want to conditionally supress the page number you can locate the textbox's "hidden" property in the property pane collapsed under "visibility". By default it is set to "false". However, you can change it to an expression of

`=iif(Globals!PageNumber = 1,True, False)`

and this will suppress the page number on Page 1. You may use any manner of expression such as

`=iif(parameters.username="Fred", True, False)`

Cheers,

CEC

> Notice that expression are in VBScript and not C#

Comment: @Cos Callis.This is from Report Designer using rdlc file. You see, the PageNumber is required for other application.But when to exporting the report programmatically, I don't want the page number to appear in the exported file say PDF.

Comment: The default behavior is that the exporter will render the report 'as is'. You would have to intercept the command to export in the reportviewer and render a different report or pass in a parameter "supressPageNo" then use it like "fred" in the example I provided.

Comment: @Cos Callis. So how you will set such kind of code from visual studio 2010 ? I know you can retrieve parameter from the report but how you to retrieve Global variables like PageNumber ?

Comment: You have to intercept the export click event from the reportviewer (or hide it and provide your own). When the user requests an export you prevent the default export and build a new report with the 'supressPageNo" parameter set to pass it in and then use it in the expression. The calling code never need be aware of the page number.

Comment: @Cos Callis, Do you have snippet how to do that "supressPageNo" ?

Comment: I don't have one put together that I can share right now. It is just a reportParameter (not a query parameter) that you can add to the report and use in the manner shown above. The trick is to use that parameter only when doing an export. The easiest way to do that is to set your _ReportViewer.ShowExportControls = false; and then create your own export controls that pass that optional report parameter and manually exporting the response.

Comment: @Cos Callis. Thank you for your help. I've got a clue. It's just creating a parameter let's say "ShowPageNo" with boolean datatype and depends on the parameter value to show or hide the page number. Like = IIF(Fields!ShowPageNo.Value = True, "Page " & Globals!PageNumber & " of " & Globals!TotalPages,"")